# jquery mobile+phonegap : search bar too wide

Tags: android, jquery-mobile, layout, cordova

I created a rather simple mobile web app with phonegap and jquery mobile: a list view with a filter (search bar). The search bar however exceeds the bounds of the screen and therefore the app allows scrolling to the left and right which is kind of ugly and unwanted behavior.
My code looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile- 1.0.min.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js">    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0/jquery.mobile-1.0.min.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
</head>
<body>

    <h2 id="list-thumb"> <img src="img/bild.png" width="96" height="34"  alt=""/> name</h2>
        <div data-demo-html="true">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="Suche">
                <li><a href="#">...
```

The result looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/GNg7c.jpg

I am trying to get my screen back to normal, i.e. no sideways scrolling possible and search bar in correct size.

UPDATE: the problem also occurs with this simple example:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href=" http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js">        </script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>


 </head>

 <body>
<ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="Search fruits..."      data-inset="false">
<li><a href="#">list1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">list2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">list3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">list4</a></li>
<li><a href="#">list5</a></li>
<li><a href="#">list6</a></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

See screenshots of the example in comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
      <div data-role="page">        
        <div data-role="content">
           <ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="Search fruits..."      data-inset="true">
<li><a href="#">list1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">list2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">list3</a></li>
<li><a href="#">list4</a></li>
<li><a href="#">list5</a></li>
<li><a href="#">list6</a></li>
</ul>
        </div>


    </div>
```

I would recommend you to read the getting started guide first :).
http://learn.jquery.com/jquery-mobile/getting-started/

Comment: Well I must have missed that 

<div data-role="page">        
        <div data-role="content">
           <ul data-role="listview" ...

:D Thanks a bunch!

Comment: It's true that filter shows too wide without <div data-role="content"> however the docs say that header, content and footer are all optional, so the fact that you need  <div data-role="content"> to make the filter width correct is a bug as far as I can tell. Either that or the docs are wrong.

Answer (score 0):

you use latest jquery and jquery-mobile link for better result

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href=" http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css" />
     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.3.2/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js></script>
```

list element

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true" data-filter-placeholder="Search fruits..." data-inset="true">
    <li><a href="#">list1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">list2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">list3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">list4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">list5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">list6</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I updated the library links to the ones above, but that did not change the behavior that I described. :(

Comment: I took the liberty to use the example from the jquery site you also used. If I use data-inset="true" (http://imgur.com/jeowi4z), the search bar gets kind of merged into the list and if I don't use it(http://imgur.com/OzlniTp), as I wanted to, I get the behavior described above, i.e. the search bar is wider than the list and hence does not show up completely on the screen and allows for scrolling sideways on the mobile device.